# How to get PHP $_GET array?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have a value in `$_GET` as an array?

If I am trying to send a link with `http://link/foo.php?id=1&id=2&id=3`, and I want to use `$_GET['id']` on the php side, how can that value be an array? Because right now `echo $_GET['id']` is returning `3`. Its the last id which is in the header link. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The usual way to do this in PHP is to put `id[]` in your URL instead of just `id`:

```
http://link/foo.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

Then `$_GET['id']` will be an array of those values. It's not especially pretty, but it works out of the box.

Comment: This is typically the way I do it, but you can process the request wihtout changing the form (see my response below using QueryString)

Comment: @DantheMan Yes, it works for POST requests as well. If you're POSTing a form you'll need inputs like this: `<input name="id[]"/> <input name="id[]" /> ...` (see Lucas' example below).

Answer (score 30):

You could make `id` a series of comma-seperated values, like this:

`index.php?id=1,2,3&name=john`

Then, within your PHP code, explode it into an array:

```
$values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);
print count($values) . " values passed.";
```

This will maintain brevity. The other (more commonly used with $_POST) method is to use array-style square-brackets:

`index.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&name=john`

But that clearly would be much more verbose.

Answer (score 18):

You can specify an array in your HTML this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="3"/>
```

This will result in this $_GET array in PHP:

```
array(
  'id' => array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3
  )
)
```

Of course, you can use any sort of HTML input, here. The important thing is that all inputs whose values you want in the 'id' array have the name `id[]`.

Answer (score 15):

You can get them using the Query String:

```
$idArray = explode('&',$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

This will give you:

```
$idArray[0] = "id=1";
$idArray[1] = "id=2";
$idArray[2] = "id=3";
```

Then

```
foreach ($idArray as $index => $avPair)
{
  list($ignore, $value) = explode("=", $avPair);
  $id[$index] = $value;
}
```

This will give you

```
$id[0] = "1";
$id[1] = "2";
$id[2] = "3";
```

Answer (score 7):

When you don't want to change the link (e.g. `foo.php?id=1&id=2&id=3`) you could probably do something like this (although there might be a better way...):

```
$id_arr = array();
foreach (explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $tmp_arr_param) {
    $split_param = explode("=", $tmp_arr_param);
    if ($split_param[0] == "id") {
        $id_arr[] = urldecode($split_param[1]);
    }
}
print_r($id_arr);
```

Comment: +1, This definitely is in need of more error checking etc. You should be using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` there, and `urldecode()` the parameter in case there are funny characters in it... But I hate PHP's `[]` with a passion, so I have in fact written a function like this once.

Answer (score 3):

I think i know what you mean, if you want to send an array through a URL you can use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

for example:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3);
$serialized_array = serialize($foo);
$url = "http://www.foo.whatever/page.php?vars=".urlencode($serialized_array);
```

and on page.php

```
$vars = unserialize($_GET['vars']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all the ids into a variable called $ids and separate them with a ",":

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

Pass them like so:

```
$url = "?ids={$ids}";
```

Process them:

```
$ids = explode(",", $_GET['ids']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, here's a code example with some explanation in comments:

```
<?php
 // Fill up array with names

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fb_registration");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{


  $a[]=$res['username'];
//$a[]=$res['password'];
}

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all hints from array if length of q>0

if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
    if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=$a[$i];
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```