# Saving double values in $_GET array

Tags: php, arrays, url, get

Let's say I have the following URL:

> http://www.site.com/index.php?size=40&size=60

If I display the `$_GET` array, the results looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [size] => 60
)
```

How can I look the `$_GET` array like this:

```
Array
(
  [size] => 40
  [size] => 60
)
```

Comment: An array can never have duplicates keys ever.

Comment: **don't** use the same variable multiple times in a URL. though it's technically valid, it's very bad practice.

Comment: URL query should be like ?size[]=40&size[]=60

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get PHP $\_GET array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array)

Comment: It's not possible to do that. It does not make sense since, to acess it, you would need to specify one of them beeing them equal.
I suggest you make the `[code]` key an array and, inside it, store that values as convenient.

Comment: It's an duplication : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206978/how-to-pass-an-array-via-get-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

Use this, the brackets, to put it in an array.

> http://www.site.com/index.php?size[]=40&size[]=60

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same keys for the **`$_GET`** superglobal array as well as any normal arrays.

Change the name of the parameters to different ones say `size1` and `size2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

URL:

http://www.site.com/index.php?size[]=40&size[]=60

PHP:

```
   foreach( $_GET["size"] as $size ){
        // Here manipulate each size    
    }
```

Of course if you want to use it all this for filters, try this:

http://www.site.com/index.php?size=40,60

and in php:

```
foreach( explode(',',$_GET["size"]) as $size ){
        // Here manipulate each size    
    }
```