# Dynamic $_GET[$value] - any ideas?

Tags: php

has anyone got a work around for this?

I have got a htaccess rule targeting L0, L1, L2, and so on... as page id's
(index.php?L0=example&L1=page1 and renames to example/page1.html)
I want to add additional get vars example/page1.html?filter=event

I thought I could do this

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_GET['L'.$i] as $key => $value) {
$pages[] = $value;  
$i++;  
}
$page_id = end($pages);
```

this doesn't work.

this would put the pages into its own array, I could then target the additional vars separately.

at present I get the page I want using 'end($_GET)' but it conflicts if I add additional get vars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the entire GET data into an array and then you can process it easily. This will give you a better understanding of the issue and you will probably have to change your strategy of getting L0, L1 as they are not GET data.

Comment: Sorry I'm unsure what you mean. I can load all the GET into an array, but I'm not sure how to target the last L value

Answer (score 1):

**PART 1** -- Incorrect Format to start with.

If you want to use the foreach structure, you need to ensure that the values passed to it are an array. Currently you are passing a non-array value to the `foreach` so it is never firing.

You should restructure your `$_GET` values so that instead of using a (manual) numeric indicator that you use an array indicator --

```
$_GET['L0'], 
$_GET['L1']
```

Becomes

```
$_GET['L'][...]
```

So your URL would be `file.php?L[]=value1&L[]=value2` etc. Then PHP can process these very tidily as a foreach loop.

See [How to get PHP $_GET array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array)

**Part 2** - Getting the value you want

This above value would/could then be processed as:

```
foreach ($_GET['L'] as $value) {
$pages[] = $value;  
}
$page_id = end($pages);
```

This means there's no need to worry about "counting" as it's all automatic and self contained. It also will (probably) make the .htaccess value assigning somewhat easier as the $_GET array name will always be the same (in this case, `L[]=`).

But in order to get the correct value you need to assign it an identifier - or a ***Key***, say you're looking for a `filter` value - What you do is manually check the "key" is the one you're looking for, so you do not define the GET array with all the same `L<number>` but for example using your foreach loop again, this time defining what the key is:

So given the URL query:

```
page.php?L[]=var1&L[filter]=var2&L[]=var3
```

The `foreach` would then be rewritten as:

```
foreach ($_GET['L'] as $key => $value) {
     if ($key == "filter"){
            $pages[$key] = $value; 
             }
       else {
         $pages[] = $value;
              }   
        }
   $page_id = $pages['filter'];
```

So then the `filter` value is defined if it is present. this means that after this process the value of the filter in PHP is `$pages['filter']` - clearly defined if present.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$i = 0;
while (isset($_GET['L' . $i])) {
    $key = 'L' . $i;
    $value = $_GET[$key];
    $pages[] = $value;
    $i++;
}
```

Your code only iterates through `$_GET['L0']`, and will fail if that is not array. So you can iterate over `$_GET` and use only those keys which start with *L*, or get those values the way I suggest.

Comment: can you add some explanation for the OP the dynamics as to why this works better than his original?

Comment: His original approach is incorrect, it raises some warnings if `$_GET['L0']` is not an array (because he's trying to iterate over `$_GET['L0']`, which is a string). If he uses a `foreach` he must iterate over all items on `$_GET`, but if he only wants to iterate some keys, I think my approach is better.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, I actually figured it out whilst waiting for a response, whether its the right way. but it works.

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
   if($key=='L'.$i){
     $pages[] = $value;
   }  
$i++;  
}
$page_id = end($pages);
```

Comment: That only works if the first key of `$_GET` is `L0`. If there's any key before that, it won't work.