# Pass two or more URL parameters in a PHP/MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, url-routing

This works:

```
searchR.php?status=pending
```

and this works:

```
searchR.php?status=rerun
```

but this doesn't (lists only "pending"):

```
searchR.php?status=pending&rerun
```

I am aiming to build a query that will list records from both terms ("pending" and "rerun")

What should the URL look like?

Comment: the ampersand signifies a new variable / parameter. What you have here is a parameter called rerun with no value

Comment: `searchR.php?status=pending&rerun` gives you  `status=pending` and `rerun=null`

Comment: you could perhaps restructure it so that the query has comma separated values and account for thetat in searchR.php. 
ie: `searchR.php?status=pending,rerun`

Comment: use like this searchR.php?status=2 ... and u can write code base on that in php

Comment: sampleIQ/searchR.php?status=pending&status=rerun lists only "rerun"

Comment: ^ Yes, only the last value

Comment: you can write so `?status[]=b&status[]=c`. Will get you `$_GET['status'] = [a,b];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get PHP $\_GET array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array)

Comment: @ stdob: no, i am not using array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sending page

```
searchR.php?status=pending|rerun
```

the receiving page

```
$Recordset1 = $_GET['status']; 
$query = ("SELECT * FROM sampleOA WHERE status REGEXP '$Recordset1' ");
```

i used the "REGEXP" expression to achieve the objective in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the ampersand to introduce a new variable and parameter to the url. example

```
searchR.php?status=$pending&rerun=$running
```

Comment: sampleIQ/searchR.php?status=pending&status=rerun lists only "rerun"

Comment: i am using $_GET['status']

Answer (score 0):

```
searchR.php?status=pending&rerun
```

gives you `status=pending` and `rerun=null`

```
searchR.php?status=pending&status=rerun
```

gives the last value `status=rerun`

```
searchR.php?status[]=pending&status[]=rerun
```

will give ayrrya $_GET['status'] = [pending,rerun];

Comment: but this requires array to string conversion which i prefer to avoid

Comment: But then what you want receive in script?

Comment: what input will be undeerstanded by search script?

Comment: $Recordset1 = $_GET['status'];
$query_Recordset1 = ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE  status = '$Recordset1' ");

Comment: No. what should be in status for some words - `a,b` or `a or b` or `a and b` or `a&b` ?