# HTML Multiple Select value as comma separated string in GET variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, jquery-select2

I have set up a multi-select list as follows:

```
<select id="cuisine-select" name="_sft_post_tag" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="banting">Banting</option>
    <option value="pasta">Pasta</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="seafood">Seafood</option>
    <option value="vegan">Vegan</option>
    <option value="vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
</select>
```

This allows the user to select multiple cuisines for their search.

When the form is submitted, the URL sets multiple GET variables of the same name each with one of the selected values, like so:

```
/restaurant/?_sft_category=saturday&_sft_post_tag=pizza&_sft_post_tag=seafood
```

I require this to pre-select tag options on the results page.

Where I am currently stuck is the structure of the URL. I require the URL to look as follows:

```
/restaurant/?_sft_category=saturday&_sft_post_tag=pizza,seafood
```

In other words, I require **one** GET variable namely **_sft_post_tag** and all selected options must appear in a comma separated string.

The Search form is part of a Wordpress plugin called Search & Filter Pro and uses comma separated strings to pre-select options. The search form from the homepage uses the Select2 plugin.

I have tried using `name="_sft_post_tag[]"` and then imploding the array into a comma separated string like so `implode(",", $_GET['_sft_post_tag'])`.

This also didn't work. At the moment it'll only pre-populate the last value of the `_sft_post_tag`

Comment: you need to stop form submission with `JS` and prepare URL by `JS` as you want URL should look like.. then use `window.location` to redirect as the form submittied ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PHP $\_GET array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array)

Comment: @RST Then you do not understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually my answer was as simple as:

```
$('#form-specials').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var cuisines = $('#cuisine-select').val().join(',');
        var day = $('#day-select').val();

        window.location = 'restaurant?_sft_category=' + day + "&_sft_post_tag=" + cuisines;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help!

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var val = $('#cuisine-select').val().join(',')
  var name = $('#cuisine-select').attr('name')
  $.get('/restaurant', {
      _sft_category: 'saturday',
      [name]: val
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="cuisine-select" name="_sft_post_tag" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="banting">Banting</option>
    <option value="pasta">Pasta</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="seafood">Seafood</option>
    <option value="vegan">Vegan</option>
    <option value="vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```